# Compiler Warning in XCode6 Beta - “Shorthand External Parameter Names”

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm playing with Swift on Xcode6 Beta, and when I'm using in a func definition '#', just like in apple's Swift programing guide, i'm getting the following compiler error:

Extraneous '#' in parameter: 'characterToFind' is already the keyword argument name

```
// this code is a copy-paste code from apple's Swift language programing guide

func containsCharacter(#string: String, #characterToFind: Character) -> Bool {
    for character in string {
        if character == characterToFind {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Is it just a bug with the new Xcode?

Comment: Can you reference where using the # is specified in the docs?

Comment: It seems to work fine for functions, but I get the same result as you in methods. Page 344

Comment: I have the same problem. I suppose it's a bug, because my code seems to be perfectly compliant with the book

Comment: @68cherries it's in “Shorthand External Parameter Names" Title.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be checking that out.

Comment: Rules for external names for methods in classes are not the same as rules for external names for functions generally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's a method (a `func` within a class), then the `#` is redundant and I suppose this is what the compiler means.

In methods, the first argument name is assumed to be only local, whereas the others are automatically assumed as both external and local names, as if you had written the `#` in front of them.

So, instead of

```
func containsCharacter(#string: String, #characterToFind: Character) -> Bool
```

you can write

```
func containsCharacter(#string: String, characterToFind: Character) -> Bool
```

and it's going to be exactly the same thing.

To further prove this point, I tried this in the playground

```
func foo(#x: Int, #y: Int) { }
class foobar {
    func foo(#x: Int, #y: Int)
    func bar(#x: Int, y: Int)
}
```

The three functions are identical, but the compiler raises a warning on the second `foo`

> Extraneous '#' in parameter: 'characterToFind' is already the keyword argument name

Again, the parameters after the first in **methods** are already automatically considered external names.